# How to make a button with 50% success possibility?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm working on a pokemon mini game project where I have a button to catch a pokemon. I want the button with 50% success possibility. May anyone help?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You have a button and when user clicks on it, it should alternatively(50%) do some action??

Comment: yes, right @DineshKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```js
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const succesWith50PercentChance = () =>
    Math.random() < 0.5 && setCounter(p => p + 1);

  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      <Button onClick={succesWith50PercentChance}>Hit Me!</Button>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57471434-WinChance]

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

let clicked = false;
class App extends Component {
  state = {};
  doSomething = () => {
    if (!clicked) {
      alert("You have 50% chance.");
    }
    clicked = !clicked;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.doSomething}>Test your luck!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What if there are multiple instances of the `App` component rendered in a UI ? In that case, the UI would cause issues because multiple `App` components would depend on the single/shared `clicked` state

Comment: Then it would be better to use the variable from state. I just wanted to give him idea about how to do it alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented as follows [using hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Note that this approach allows for multiple "50% chance" buttons to exist in your app, that operate independent of one another without any conflict:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const ChanceButon = () => {

  /* Define local state for button component, starting with false */
  const [ clicked, setClicked ] = React.useState(false);

  const onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(clicked) {
      alert('Shown 50% of the time');
    }

    /* Toggle clicked state */
    setClicked( Math.random() > 0.5 );

  }

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Test your luck!</button>
}

{ /* Usage: you can have multiple instances would issue or conflict between them */
<ChanceButon />
<ChanceButon />
<ChanceButon />
```